# Cannot read from beginning of topic using segmentio/kafka-go

Tags: go, apache-kafka, segment-io

I am unable to read from the beginning of a topic using [kafka-go](https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go). Here's how I create the reader:

```
    reader := kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
        Brokers: []string{"127.0.0.1:9092"},
        GroupID: "my-group-id",
        Topic:   "my-topic",
    })
    reader.SetOffset(0)

    for {
        message, err := reader.ReadMessage(context.Background())

        if err != nil {
            log.Errorln("ReadMessage failed:", err)
        }

        log.Info("Received: ", string(message.Value))
        ...
```

I've tried passing `kafka.FirstOffset` and `kafka.LastOffset` as well but all result in the reading from the latest offset when I restart my app. I get the same result if I set the `StartOffset` field to `0` in the `kafka.ReaderConfig` object.

Comment: Think this is what you want https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go/issues/297

Comment: Setting `StartOffset` didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

In order to specify the start offset, I had to specify the partition:

```
reader := kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
    Brokers: []string{"127.0.0.1:9092"},
    Topic:   "my-topic",
    Partition: 0,
    StartOffset: 0,
})
```

You cannot specify both `GroupID` and `Partition` to set the `StartOffset`.

Comment: You should ideally not assign specific partitions. What happens if you want a topic with multiple partitions?

Comment: One partition is good enough for our use case.